# UITableViewCell does not respect device modifier in search

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller, ios-universal-app

I have a UITableViewCell in a xib named MyCell.xib and MyCell~ipad.xib for a universal application. When the table view loads (queue cell for reuse, and dequeue as per usual) everything looks fine. However, when using the UISearchDisplayController (using the same typical dequeue-ing as before), the ~ipad xib is not used and it defaults to the general xib.

Not sure what would be helpful to see here, so feel free to ask for more information. I need to be able to use device modifiers on my xibs for these cells to adjust font sizes and icon sizes properly.

Registering cell in viewDidLoad

```
self.table.register(UINib(nibName: XIBFiles.TEAMCELL, bundle:nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: self.GENERATEDCELL)
```

Code for getting cell for row

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if tableView == self.table {
            if self.bottomCell != nil && indexPath.row == data!.count {
                return bottomCell!
            }
            else{
                return self.cellForObject(data![(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row])
            }
        }
        else {
            return self.cellForObject(searchData[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row])
        }
    }
```

Helper code for getting cell

```
//Set up search controllers
        func cellForObject(object) -> UITableViewCell {
            let teamCell = tableController.table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: self.GENERATEDCELL) as! TeamCell

            teamCell.team = (object as! Team)
            return teamCell
        }
```

Comment: Generally, it is preferred to use autolayout rather than multiple Xib files. Please show the code where you dequeue the cells

Comment: @Paulw11 See above. In this case, I need a Xib file specific to the iPad and one for iPhones. The cell renders fine using the ~ipad view until a search is made. At that point, it does not use the ~ipad xib.

Comment: Huh. I didn't know about (or perhaps have forgotten about since it is so old) the ~iPad  thing.  This may be a bug but UISearchDisplayController was deprecated in iOS8, so you may not get any joy from Apple.

Comment: thanks @Paulw11. Turns out it was actually an issue with auto-layout of cells. You have to set cell heights to automatic for your table AND for the display controller's table. I was missing that second piece.